# How to fix 401 response from axios PUSH request to Spotify's API

Tags: reactjs, axios, authorization, spotify

I'm trying to create a new spotify playlist using axios and I keep getting a 401 response.

here is the axios request:

```
const response = await axios.post(
      `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${this.state.userID}/playlists`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.state.token}`,
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
          "name": "New Playlist",
          "description": "New playlist description",
          "public": true,
        },
      }
    );
```

Here is how I got the token:
`` <Button href={`${this.state.AUTH_ENDPOINT}?client_id=${this.state.CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${this.state.REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=${this.state.RESPONSE_TYPE}&scope=${this.state.SCOPE}`}>Login to Spotify</Button> ``

Here is how the scope is defined:
`SCOPE: encodeURIComponent('playlist-modify-public'),`

I tried changing around the data inputted or whether it was single quotes/double and nothing seemed to affect it.

Update: I found a post about this and it fixed it: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/401-error-on-all-PUT-requests/m-p/5585662#M9316